# libgdx get key pressed

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I'm working on a game with libgdx, the game only has one button witch makes the player jump. I'm trying to figure out a way to make it possible for the user to rebind that key to whatever key they want. In the keyUp and keyDown methods you get a keycode and im wondering if there is any other way to check what key that is instead of going over all the keys like.

```
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.A){}
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.B){}
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.C){}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Libgdx so try this

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ANY_KEY)) {
     // your actions
     jump();
}
```

Put this code inside the **render()** function so the **jump()** function will be called if any key of keyboard is pressed

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you! With a little reworking of how my input class works I got it to work :)